React 18.3 causes a lot of `act` warnings in tests
I have the following component - "A toggle button":
// ToggleButton.tsx

export function ToggleButton() {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick={() => setIsEnabled((prev) => !prev)}}
      data-testid="toggle-button"
    >
      {isEnabled ? (
        <span>Light Mode</span>
      ) : (
        <span>Dark Mode</span>
      )}
    </button>
  );
}

I have a simple test that checks that the button displays the correct text after each click:
it('toggles between light and dark mode when clicked', async () => {
    render(<ToggleButton />);

    // Initial state should be Light Mode
    expect(screen.getByText('Light Mode')).toBeInTheDocument();

    // Click the button
    const button = screen.getByTestId('toggle-button');
    await userEvent.click(button);

    // Should now show Dark Mode
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByText('Dark Mode')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    // Click again
    await userEvent.click(button);

    // Should be back to Light Mode
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByText('Light Mode')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });

I am getting a warning:
Warning: An update to ToggleButton inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */

I see that I can wrap await user.click in act and the warning goes away, but I am wondering if that is the correct approach since as far as I understand userEvent.click is already wrapped in act by default.
I am wondering if I am not simply silencing the test this way and is there perhaps a way to adjust what I am testing for to solve this warning? Also it would be helpful to know what change in React 18.3 introduced this change.
Here is a stackblitz sandbox to reproduce the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/sb1-ppnfh1?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FToggleButton.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2F__tests__%2FToggleButton.test.tsx
